# How to use Next.js Image component with MaterialUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am able to use the `<img>` tag no problem, but when I try to use the `<Image>` component, all that displays is an empty square the size of the image. The only way I have been able to get the image to display without using `<img>` is with the `<Avatar>` component. It's just a small brand image so it's not a huge deal, but I would like to use the built-in Next.js image optimization. And using `<Avatar>` does not feel very semantic as well.

It is being displayed inside of a ListItem component like this:

```
<Drawer variant="permanent" {...other}>
            <List disablePadding>
                <ListItem
                    sx={{
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <Avatar
                        src="images/icons/agreement2.png"
                        alt="Scales of Justice Brand Image"
                        sx={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                    />
                </ListItem>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

1. I created a separate component for the image

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import brandImage from '../public/images/icons/law.png'

export default function Brand() {
    return <Image src={brandImage} width="50px" height="50px" alt="Brand Logo" />
}
```

and displaying `<Brand />` inside of the `<ListItem>` in place of the current `<Avatar>` component.

2. I tried to import the .png file and use

```
<Image src={brandImage} width="50px" height="50px" alt="Brand Logo" />
```

inside of the `<ListItem>`. And then I tried without importing the image and just using the full file path.

3. I tried placing `<Image`> inside of the `<Avatar>` component.

```
<Avatar>
<Image src={brandImage} width="50px" height="50px" alt="Brand Logo" />
</Avatar>
```

I also tried adding in the `layout` prop with all of the options.

I am using Next.js v12.0.9 and MUI v5.4.2

Comment: could you solve the issue without setting fixed height to an image? @Steve

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a parent element with a position responsive and setting the image like this:

```
<Box sx={{position:'relative'}}>
<Image src={brandImage} width="50px" height="50px" alt="Brand Logo" />
</Box>
```

You also may set it like:

```
<Box sx={{position:'relative', height:'50px', width:'50px'}}>
    <Image src={brandImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Brand Logo" />
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me.

```
<Stack
 sx={{
   height: "500px",
 }}
>
  <Image
          src={image.data.attributes.url}
          alt={image.data.attributes.alternativeText}
          width={image.data.attributes.width}
          height={image.data.attributes.height}          
          objectFit="cover"
          priority
   />
</Stack>
```

Using Stack seems to expand the image full width without using width: 100%